# How to ensure order advice for two point cuts matching the same join point in Aspectj and AOP

Tags: json, spring, aop, aspectj, pointcut

I'm planning on using Spring Security using Spring AOP. It will have it's own point cuts for all public methods on controller classes. The methods will be picked out by class name and public method, perhaps partial argument signatures.

I also want to encapsulate the code that checks for headers, good json, good json request object, and authentication and insert that into public methods of controller classes. Since I will have both JSON-RPC and JSON-REST, there will be a total of THREE Point Cuts accessing the public methods described above.

Spring Security will insert advice on all methods, JSON-RPC point cut will take care of that controller class, and JSON-REST point cut will take care of its controller class.

How can I ensure the order of operation of the two pieces of advice? I want the security stuff to run first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@Order` annotation

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html

You have not given more information about how you have setup your aop to point out exactly how this can be used in your structure.

You can implement the Ordered interface and then via xml configuration pass the order e.g. -

```
<bean id="xyz" class="com.abc.XYZ">
     <property name="order" value="34"/>  
</bean>
```

Comment: From what I read on your link, that is for annotation based point cuts. I am hoping to avoid that, so that the advice is automatic without the programmer having to worry about it. Do you know if there is a way to do ordering without the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

A good link with an answer:
   [aspect ADK 1.5 Notebook](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-declare.html)

Another link that I wish to quote from:
  [answer](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/advanced-aspectj-part-iv-declaring-aspects-precedence/)

> To declare aspect precedence, you can use the special keyword
>
> ```
> declare precedence : <Type1Pattern>,<Type2Pattern>…<TypeNPattern>;
> ```
>
> In the above example, aspect1has precedence over aspect2, which in
>   turn has precedence over aspect3 etc. until aspectN.
>
> By “has precedence over“, we mean “is executed before“. Generally the
>   aspect with highest executes first. The execution order also depends
>   on the type of advice.
>
> ```
> the aspect with highest precedence kicks in before the lowest precedence aspect for before() advice
> the aspect with highest precedence kicks in after the lowest precedence aspect for after() advice
> the aspect with highest precedence wraps around the lowest precedence aspect for around() advice
> ```
>
> One best practice in AspectJ is to declare a special aspect whose task
>   consists simply of declaring precedence for other aspects.
>
> Example:   public aspect MyAspectsOrdering {
>       declare precedence : around1, around2, before3, before4, after5;
>       declare precedence : Transactional*, around4;
>       declare precedence : *, before2; }